# I have a missing matching_table.conf

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

when I enter `/usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf /usr/cygnus/conf/ -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf -n cygnusagent -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console` I get the output:

```
2015-04-22 14:45:14,308 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-4) [ERROR - es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.interceptors.DestinationExtractor.initialize(DestinationExtractor.java:84)] Runtime error (File not found. Details=/usr/cygnus/conf/matching_table.conf (No such file or directory))
2015-04-22 14:45:14,309 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-4) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:253)] Unable to start EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource{name:http-source,state:IDLE} } - Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Running HTTP Server found in source: http-source before I started one.Will not attempt to start.
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
at org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource.start(HTTPSource.java:137)
at org.apache.flume.source.EventDrivenSourceRunner.start(EventDrivenSourceRunner.java:44)
at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Any solution to the missing matching_table.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch! This is a bug that will be fixed in next release. Cygnus installer forgets to rename the `/usr/cygnus/conf/matching_table.conf.template` as `/usr/cygnus/conf/mathing_table.conf`. The workaround is as simple as renaming that file by hand.